# Kotlin - Is it possible to check for operator precedence

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, operator-precedence

Let's say I have the following class:

```kotlin
data class Foo(var name: String) {
    operator fun plus(foo: Foo): Foo {
        name += foo.name
        return this
    }
}
```

Which is then used like this:

```kotlin
val foo1 = Foo("1")
val foo2 = Foo("2")
val foo3 = Foo("3")

foo1+foo2+foo3
println(foo1.name) // 123
```

Now, what if I wanted different behavior depending on whether the operations are chained like this:

```
foo1+foo2+foo3
```

Or like this:

```
(foo1+foo2)+foo3
```

In both cases foo1's name would be 123, but let's say that in the second case I would want foo1's name to be (12)3.

Is there a way to add a condition to the plus function, which checks whether the foo that it is called on originates from within parentheses/has a higher precedence or not.

Comment: `+` is left associative, so `foo1+foo2+foo3` is exactly the same as, and indistinguishable from `(foo1+foo2)+foo3`. It is, however, different from `foo1+(foo2+foo3)`.

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a good practice to overload the arithmetic operators to mutate an object. It breaks convention, which makes it hard to follow the code.

Comment: Could this then be done by creating a new foo for each arithmetic operator, which includes some additional data?

Comment: (Technically, I think what you're describing is known as the _associativity_ — left or right — since an operator must have the same precedence as itself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible, because that makes no sense tbh. The compiler will just resolve the order of operations, brackets just indicate that 1+2 should resolve first and the result should be added to 3. There is no concept of brackets anymore in that result, you just have the outcome.

What is confusing you is that you are abusing the plus function to do something people wouldn't expect. You should not use the plus function to mutate the object it is called upon, this is not expected behaviour. Users will expect the plus function to return a new object not a mutation of the left or right operand.

In your case:

```
operator fun plus(foo: Foo): Foo {
    return Foo(name += foo.name)
}
```

Don't do something different lest you want other people to be really confused. Fyi plusAssign is a mutating function, but still wouldn't allow you to do what you want. To achieve that you'd probably need to write your own parser and parse the operands and operators yourself.

Comment: Damn, I was really hoping that this could be done. It would have been useful, because I wanted to create a DSL API which you could use to build DAGs from symbolic equations. Also, I'll take into account to not mutate the object with operators in the future.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to represent the equation as a string, and write a parser...

Comment: Well, what you are trying to do is simply more low-level than what those functions are intended for.  On the plus side you are essentially trying to 'write your own calculator', which is a common exercise in many languages (including kotlin eg. https://github.com/Keelar/ExprK), so it might not be too complex to adapt one of those to do what you want.

Comment: Well, in my case I would want to do more than just evaluating the equation. The primary use case for me would be figuring out the exponents for the variables in an equation. For example the equation a=b/c could also be represented as: a=b*c^(-1.0).